# MobaXterm keeps changing location of DISPLAY on different computer logins?

Tags: windows, x11, xserver, mobaxterm, wsl-2

I am using MobaXterm with WSL2 as a terminal and X client, and I am having issues with MobaXterm changing its DISPLAY variable seemingly randomly. It seems that the IP remains the same on a given boot-up of the computer, but changes from day to day (or maybe every couple of days?).

I have been setting DISPLAY on my WSL2 installation via `~/.bashrc` (so it is persistent) as what is told to me on the MobaXterm start screen (usually something like `192.168.1.Y:0.0`, where Y is a different number that seems to change).

When I change DISPLAY, everything works as it should, until I receive an error to connect to display some day, and I check to see the Y value / DISPLAY location has changed. Again, I can check what MobaXterm displays above as "Your DISPLAY is set to as ..." and manually change it via ~/.bashrc, but I would love to set it once and have it just work.

My colleagues who use MobaXterm seem to have their DISPLAY as consistently set to something like 'localhost', but mine seems to show some sort of full IP address everytime (that changes).

Is anyone familiar with this problem, and/or have any idea on how can I fix this?

Adding an example from the MobaXterm bash terminal on my WSL2 distro:

```
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: 127.0.0.1:0.0
$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

As soon as I set `export DISPLAY=192.168.1.13:0.0` (which is what MobaXterm is saying the DISPLAY is set to right now), `xeyes` displays fine.

Someone also led me to the [MobaXterm documentation](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#6_2_5):

> By default, MobaXterm Xserver listens on all your network adapters.
>   The banner message will say that your DISPLAY environment is set to ":0.0", but this is an informational message only: it is printed here in order to help users set their "DISPLAY" environment variable when connected to a remote server. However, the embedded X11 server listens on all network interfaces, not only the one which is written in. It does not matter which IP address you see in the "DISPLAY" variable: as MobaXterm X server listens on all your network interfaces, it also listens on the 2nd, 3rd, (...) network interfaces. For instance, if your computer has 2 network adapters (192.168.0.10 and 10.10.10.36): MobaXterm says your DISPLAY is set to "192.168.0.10:0.0". However **the X server really listens on "127.0.0.1" (localhost)**, "192.168.0.10:0.0" (1st adapter) and "10.10.10.36:0.0" (2nd adapter).

All right, if it is indeed the case that "the X server really listens on "127.0.0.1" (localhost)," shouldn't my X applications launch correctly when DISPLAY (on the WSL2 distro) is set to `127.0.0.1:0.0` or `localhost:0.0`?

Answer (score 3):

Similar problem here. I'd have to copy the DISPLAY IP address from the banner, and assign it to `$DISPLAY` each time it changed.

I wanted to derive it dynamically, but in my case X server was not listening on ANY of the interfaces that Linux had any knowledge of (contrary to what's asserted in MobaXterm docs).

It was only listening on the Wi-Fi port, which ostensibly, Linux-WSL2 cannot access natively.

Fortunately it does have access to Windows commands! So the workaround that solved it for me was adding the following to `.bashrc`

```
export DISPLAY="$(netsh.exe interface ip show address "Wi-Fi"|awk '/IP Address/ {print $3}'|sed 's/\r//'):0"
```

Comment: What should I do if this doesn't work? I use MobaXTerm. I have a problem where sometimes when I install WSL2 X11 works, and sometimes it doesn't. I've tried many possibilities for DISPLAY, including the solution you give above.

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue?

Comment: The interface may have different names. I have `Wi-Fi 2`. So run  `netsh.exe interface ip show address` to check actual names.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between WSL 1 and WSL 2 is that WSL 1 runs 'within' your windows environment and WSL 2 runs as a virtual computer 'besides' your windows environment.

WSL 1 shares the network with the host Windows environment, while in WSL 2 it has it's own. The special IP address 127.0.0.1 (localhost) always points to the machine  you are connecting from. That's why in WSL 1 127.0.0.1 will point to the windows environment where MobaXterm is running (because they are the same machine), but in WSL 2, 127.0.0.1 points to the Linux environment where no MobaXterm is running (because it is a different, albeit virtual, machine).

You need to point your WSL 2 virtual machine to the Windows machine by specifying the IP address of the Windows machine. This IP address is set by Windows itself, MobaXterm has no control over it. That's why the only thing MobaXTerm can do is get the IP address from Windows and tell the user what it is; it cannot by itself set the IP address to something static.

You can in most cases ensure that Windows has a static IP address. In my case, the IP address that MobaXTerm shows me is the IP address that my windows machine gets from my WiFi router. In order to give it a static IP address, I have to logon to my router (on http://192.168.1.1), and tell it to always assign the same IP address to the windows machine. The exact way to do this is different for each router, usually somewhere in the 'DHCP' settings.

The IP range 192.168.*.* is a local network, so only computers in your network (your home) can access it. From the addresses in the question it seems that you can also configure your router on http://192.168.1.1. This is a different 192.168.1.1 than mine.

Comment: By the way, with WSL 2, both Windows and Linux run on the Microsoft Hypervisor. So they really run 'next to each other', unlike with WSL 1.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is x server changes listening port.
How I've fixed that:

```
export X11PORT=$(netstat -4 -l -n | grep 127.0.0.1:60 | head -1 | sed -En "s/.*127.0.0.1:60([1-9][0-9]).*/\1/p")
echo "X11PORT=$X11PORT"
export DISPLAY=localhost:${X11PORT}.0
```